# base64 decryption gives same results

Tags: base64

If I decrypt authorization code MTAzMjAwNjk6ODU2ODVh using base64, I am getting  10320069:85685a which is correct and expected.

But If I decrypt just adding single numeric or alpha numeric character at the endof the authorization key (eg: MTAzMjAwNjk6ODU2ODVhZ )(Which is incorrect authorization code) still I am getting 10320069:85685a

Is this a known issue in base64 ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Base64 is **not** encryption, it is encoding.
2. Base64 is not broken, assume your code (which you did not provide) is broken.
3. Base64 encoding is always a multiple of 4 bytes in length so the addition of a single character creates invalid Base64 and the implementation is ignoring that erroneous error and probably providing an error indication.

Please supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).